# Adding data to MS Access using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

My school project is to make a website where people can sell/buy used school items like calculators etc. I am using ASP.net & vb.net in Microsoft Visual Studio.

My problem is that I don't really get how to add the data filled in on the website, inserted into the MS Access database file. The problem is that the information is spread over 2 tables.

I've tried to use 2 different SQL statements, 1 for each table, but this doesn't work out either. I've changed the format of the database a bit and I think that now the problem is to input the relation between the 2 tables but I have no idea how to.

I have this code running right now

```
    Protected Sub bntVerzenden_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bntVerzenden.Click



    Dim VerkopenConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim VerkopenCommArtikel, VerkopenCommGebruiker As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    VerkopenConn.ConnectionString = My.Settings.SvShopConnection
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Connection = VerkopenConn
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Connection = VerkopenConn

    'Gebruiker gegevens aan de database toevoegen
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblGebruiker (GebruikersNaam, GebruikersVoornaam, GebruikersEmail, GebruikersGSM) VALUES (@GebruikersNaam, @GebruikersVoornaam, @GebruikersEmail, @GebruikersGSM)"

    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersNaam", txtNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersVoornaam", txtVNaam.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersEmail", txtEmail.Text)
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GebruikersGSM", txtGsm.Text)

    'Artikel gegevens aan de database toevoegen
    VerkopenCommArtikel.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblArtikel (ArtikelBeschrijving, ArtikelPrijs, RubriekNaam, ArtikelAankoopdatum, ArtikelTekoopgezet, ArtikelBeschikbaar) VALUES ( @ArtikelBeschrijving, @ArtikelPrijs, @RubriekNaam, @ArtikelAankoopdatum, @ArtikelTekoopgezet, @ArtikelBeschikbaar)"

    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschrijving", txtArtikelBeschrijving.Text)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelPrijs", txtArtikelPrijs.Text)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RubriekNaam", lstRubriek.SelectedItem.ToString)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelAankoopdatum", CalAankoop.SelectedDate)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelTekoopgezet", calVerkoop.SelectedDate)
    VerkopenCommArtikel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArtikelBeschikbaar", True)

    If VerkopenConn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then VerkopenConn.Open()
    VerkopenCommGebruiker.ExecuteNonQuery()
    VerkopenCommArtikel.ExecuteNonQuery()






End Sub
```

End Class

With this error at the second `ExecuteNonQuery`:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblGebruiker'.

The first query works and that data has been added to the database.

Database relations down below.

[Relations](http://imgur.com/O9zV7Tv)

Comment: Does it give any errors when it runs? Also, could you post some details about your access database?

Comment: You're missing `RubriekID` in your columns section of your second query.

Comment: @amber Edited the code and edited the question.

Comment: @lamelemon the relations can be seen in this post.

Comment: @ThimoDemey  Yeah, I saw that afterwards again.  Just as a test, try removing the relationship between `tblArtikel` and `tblGebruiker`.  Then run the query.

Comment: @lamelemon after deleting the relation between tblArtikel & tblGebruiker do i recieve this error → Additional information: You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table 'tblRubriek'.

Comment: @ThimoDemey That means there is no entry in `tblRubriek` with the `RubriekID` you specified.

Comment: @amber  tblRubriek  is not empty in my database, if that is what you mean. http://imgur.com/KSLjnQG

Comment: @ThimoDemey and your insert statement is using 1 or 2 for `RubriekID`?

Comment: @lamelemon yes it does. It uses the selected_Index of a listbox where 2 'Rubrieken' are shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your first exception was because you were missing a column in your query.  This second exception is PROBABLY caused by you having a one-to-one relationship defined between `tblArtikel` and `tblRubriek`.  You need to change the relationship to one-to-many to allow duplcates, in this case.  `tblRubriek` would be the "one" side and `tblArtikel` would be the "many" side.  Because you have one primary key in `tblRubriek` that associates with "many" rows in `tblArtikel`.

Comment: So in 'tblArtikel' do I have to use 'RubriekNaam' instead of 'RubriekID' and make the relation with 'RubriekNaam' in 'tblRubriek' , right?

Comment: `RubriekID` is not a primary key in `tblArtikel`, so it shouldn't be a problem to insert it, but you do need to mention that it need to be inserted "INSERT INTO tblArtikel (**RubriekID,** ArtikelBeschrijving, ArtikelPrijs, ArtikelAankoopdatum, ArtikelTekoopgezet) VALUES (@RubriekID, @ArtikelBeschrijving, @ArtikelPrijs, @ArtikelAankoopdatum, @ArtikelTekoopgezet)"

Comment: @ThimoDemey Sorry.  As I mentioned above, the query that Amber posted is what you should have.  But the relationship you defined may be the issue.

Comment: I've changed the query but still have the same error.